# Replace dots by carriage return with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have got a file txt which contains music lyrics.

I want to replace all dots by a carriage return to have something more readable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(get-content file.txt) -replace '\.',"`n" | out-file newfile.txt
```

The -replace operater uses a regex match, so you need to escape the dot to make it match a literal dot.  Otherwise it will replace every character in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough:

```
Get-Content C:\Imagine_Lyrics.txt | % {$_.Replace('.', "`n")} | Out-File C:\Imagine_Lyrics2.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: I think you forgot to close the bracket.